# Get texture of Sprite in cocos 2dx

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, game-engine

i have developed `cocos 2dx` game in which i am running `animation` in the `Sprite` in which i want to get the current `texture name` for that i have tried following code:

```
CCSpriteFrame *frameN =   fisherManBoat->displayFrame();
frameName = frameN->_textureFilename;
```

But it gives me error that `textureFilename` is protected so how can i resolve it ? If it doesn't work then what else i can try? Because there is a button on the screen on which i tap and animation runs, i want to make it smooth. So, that if animation is in between on taping again it doesn't starts from again but from its current point.

Comment: Hold the filenames/textures in a vector instance variable?  You will probably also need an index instance variable so you know which element in the vector is currently in use.

Comment: But again how will i get the current animating frame of the sprite ? @trojanfoe

Comment: You will know it as you set it.  There is no mystery to what is the current frame as you are defining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to access the _textureFilename variable the you need to modify the  CCSpriteFrame.h file.

First you need to find this code in CCSpriteFrame.h file

```
protected:
    Vec2 _offset;
    Size _originalSize;
    Rect _rectInPixels;
    bool   _rotated;
    Rect _rect;
    Vec2 _offsetInPixels;
    Size _originalSizeInPixels;
    Texture2D *_texture;
    std::string  _textureFilename;
    PolygonInfo _polygonInfo;
```

And cut below line from this code

```
std::string  _textureFilename;
```

now you have to paste it on top of CCSpriteFrame.h file where Public Scope is define.

```
class CC_DLL SpriteFrame : public Ref, public Clonable
{
public:

    std::string  _textureFilename;
```

I hope it will help you. Thanks.

Comment: That's a pretty bad idea and will cause a never-ending maintenance problem for very little benefit.

Comment: I am just giving the simple solution for asked question. if you have better Solution then please answer it.@trojanfoe.

Comment: Most Welcome @WaleedAhmed